# How to update the databound elements in the UI in a cached page?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime

In my app (GroupItemsPage) I have several groups with items (showing some news). If a user scrolls to the right and chooses an item, he is redirected to a details page. If he returns, the same group should still be displayed. I could achieve this behaviour by adding NavigationCacheMode="Enabled" to the XAML (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14605103/groupeditemspage-view-jumps-back-to-start-when-navigating-back-from-detailpage/14606891#14606891)). This works like a charm.

But unfortunately, after this, the page is not updated anymore. On this GroupItemsPage I display the number of unread items (with databinding). Unfortunately, this is not updated anymore since the page is cached.

How can I have both behaviors (update gui with databinding and persisting the chosen page)?

Edit: The GroupItemsPage looks the following. I marked the things I need to update (they are databound).

[image: Tagi-News for Windows 8 - marked things I want to update in a cached page]

Answer (score 0):

Events Loaded and Unloaded will always be called when navigating to and away from page regardless of cache settings.

If you want to load/update data in cached page, use Loaded event.

EDIT: There is another solution for your problem.
Define a private field _isLoaded which will tell you if data is loaded.

```
private bool _isLoaded;
```

Then in constructor set Loaded event:

```
Loaded += OnLoaded;
```

And then use this code in OnLoaded method to load or update your UI:

```
        if (_isLoaded)
        {
            // Update your UI
        }
        else
        {
            _isLoaded = true;
            // Initialize your UI (data loading, data binding, etc.)
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. In the loaded event method, what should I do there? As I databound the information to this cached page, I don't know how to change it...? Thanks!

Comment: If your page is layout aware (BasicPage template) than you'll have LoadState and SaveState. LoadState will be called only first time and this is where you do data loading, data binding, etc.Load event will be called every time you get to this page and you can do updates but you don't need to load data again or do data binding.

Comment: hi Jernej. THanks. I got this one, but I don't know hot to Update my UI (if _isLoaded = true). I have a grouped list of items on this page and want to update the items (if there are new) and the number of unread items... (see Screenshot in my first post). Thank you!

Comment: It is difficult to help you remotely but generally you need to call web services or download data or similar. Updating data can be similar to loading data but instead of creating UI elements your updating them.

How to solve this problem is very specific to your implementation of the project and there are only general advices how to achieve.
Tell me more, how you load data and apply it to UI and I might be able to help with your problem.

Comment: hi Jernej. Sorry for my very late answer (I had exams). Basically, I have an ObervableCollection with a Group of items. Each of those groups has a list on its own with all the news-items (and an int with the number of unread items). Moreover, I have a property (in each group) for the number of unread items. I just make a basic databinding of those properties to the view (like all the Win8-App samples do. Updating the variable(s) works very fine as long as I disable the NavigationCacheMode... Thanks for your help!!